# Cómo pasar los datos de un archivo JSON provenientes de una API a un componente hermano

Tags: reactjs

Resulta que tengo varios componentes, en App definí mi archivo de rutas a diferentes páginas, home, trainer, user y admin, cada una de ellas tienen subcomponentes, header, navbar, body, etc.. En home/header/login, es donde se encuentran la función para logearse, la cuál funciona perfectamente y redirige asu página correspondiente, ahora es cuando me surge el inconveniente, ¿ Cómo puedo recoger los datos del JSON que me devuelve el servicio si dicho login no pertenece a la página que redirige?,
Muchas gracias

```
Home/header/Login.js

`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

/* FUNCIONES */
import { PostData } from '../../services/PostData'

export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            redirect: false,
            type: '',
        }

        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    login() {

        if (this.state.email && this.state.password) {
            PostData('login', this.state).then((result) => {
                let responseJSON = result;
                console.log(responseJSON)

                if (responseJSON.userData) {

                    /* Cookie de sesión */
                    sessionStorage.setItem('userData', responseJSON);

                    /* Logeo satisfactorio */
                    this.setState({
                        redirect: true,
                        type: responseJSON.userData.type
                    });

                } else {

                    /* Acceso denegado */
                    console.log("no entras")
                }
            })
        } else {
            console.log("Contraseña o email incorrectos")
        }
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            //Con e.target.name, recogemos el valor según el name del input
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
        //console.log(this.state)
    }

    render() {

        // Redirige a la página cuando el usuario haya sido logeado
        if (this.state.redirect) {

            if (this.state.type === 'admin') {
                return (<Redirect to='/admin' />)
            }

            if (this.state.type === 'trainer') {
                return (<Redirect to='/trainer' />)
            }

            if (this.state.type === 'user') {
                return (<Redirect to='/user?pepe' />)
            }

        }

        return (

            <div className="col-sm-7">

                <input
                    type="email"
                    className="form-control email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    name="email"
                    maxLength="40"
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                />

                <input
                    type="password"
                    className="form-control password"
                    id="password"
                    placeholder="Contraseña"
                    name="password"
                    maxLength="15"
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                />

                <button
                    type="submit"
                    name="submit"
                    className="btn btn-green"
                    onClick={this.login}
                >
                    Entrar
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}`
```

/User

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

/* ------------------ */
/*     COMPONENTS     */
/* ------------------ */

import Header from './Header/Header';
import Navbar from '../GeneralComponents/Navbar/Navbar';
import Footer from '../GeneralComponents/Footer/Footer';

export default class UserPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            redirect: false,
        }

        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('userData')) {
            console.log("Call user feed")
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                redirect: true
            });
        }
    }

    logout = () => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("userData", '');
        sessionStorage.clear();

        this.setState({
            redirect: true
        });
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return <Redirect to='/' />
        }

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Header logout={this.logout} />
                <Navbar />
                <Footer />
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado por mi cuenta, pero me gustaría publicar como lo he solucionado por si alguien se ve en la misma situación:

En login.js, añadir el siguiente código, para pasar los datos como variable de sesión:

```
login() {
if (this.state.email && this.state.password) {
  PostData("login", this.state).then(result => {
    let responseJSON = result;
    //console.log(responseJSON)

    if (responseJSON.userData) {

      // Pasa los datos en sessión
      sessionStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(responseJSON));

      /* Logeo satisfactorio */
      this.setState({
        type: responseJSON.userData.type,
        isLogged: true,
        redirect: true
      });

      //console.log(this.state.userData)
      //console.log(this.state.isLogged)
    } else {
      /* Acceso denegado */
      console.log("no entras");
    }
  });
}
```

}

Y en /User recoger los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
componentWillMount() {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem("userData")) {
        console.log("call user feed")
        const data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("userData"))

        this.setState({
            userData:data.userData
        })
    } 
    else {
        this.setState({
            redirect:true
        })
    }
}
```